# How to insert data to table on SQL server using jQuery on blazor server side?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on `blazor server side` .I face issue I can't apply jQuery to insert data to SQL server database table owner .

after apply script and check table SQL server no rows inserted

so my issue jQuery not insert data

my code as below :

1 - I create JS file insertdata.js on `wwwroot folder js` folder and add following code :

```
function insertData(owner) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/Owner/AddOwnerFile',
                    data: JSON.stringify(owner),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('Data inserted successfully!');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error inserting data!');
                    }
                });
            }
```

2 - web API will executed by jQuery as below

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOwnerFile(object owner)
        {
            var ownerDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(owner.ToString());
           
               string ownerfileno = ownerDict["employeeID"].ToString();
            
            
           
              string departementCode = ownerDict["departementCode"].ToString();
            
            
           

            var sql = "INSERT INTO Owner (OwnerFileNo, DepartementCode) VALUES ({0}, {1})";
            var rowsAffected = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, ownerfileno, departementCode);

            return Ok();
         
        }
```

3 - on razor page I invoke function as below

```
public async Task InsertData(EmployeeDetails owner)
    {
        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("insertData", owner);
    }
```

4 - on _Host file my scripts file as below

```
<head>
   
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
 <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

 <script src="~/assets/js/insertdata.js"></script>
 <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

5-on html and related function insert as below :

```
       <span class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize font-weight-bold">Owner File No</span>
                                            &nbsp&nbsp
                                            <div class="autocomplete w-25">
                                                <input id="autocomp" @bind=selectedEmployeeId @oninput=HandleInput class="form-control filter" style=" width:200px;" />
                                                @if (emp is not null)
                                                {
                                                    <ul class="options">
                                                        @if (emp.Any())
                                                        {
                                                            @foreach (var em in emp)
                                                            {
                                                                <li class="option" @onclick=@(_ => Selectemp(em.employeeID))>
                                                                    <span class="option-text">@em.employeeID</span>
                                                                </li>
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            <li class="disabled option">No results</li>
                                                        }
                                                    </ul>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                   
                                  
                                   
                                       
                                            <span class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize font-weight-bold" style="width:160px;">Department Code</span>
                                            &nbsp&nbsp
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@emddata.departementCode" />
                                    
                                
                                   
                                </div>
                         

@code
{
 public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public int employeeID { get; set; }
        public string departementCode { get; set; }

    }
public EmployeeDetails emddata = new EmployeeDetails();
async Task  Selectemp(string id)
    {
        selectedEmployeeId = id;
        selectedEmployeeId = emp!.First(c => c.employeeID.Equals(selectedEmployeeId)).employeeID;
        appsdata.OwnerFileNo = selectedEmployeeId;
        InsertData(emddata);
          
}
```

**last Updated post**

can any one help me to solving my issue using jQuery I need to know how

to solve current issue using jQuery May  I will use blazor direct but

I need to know how to solve current issue using jQuery

Comment: There's a lot of code posted here which makes me think you need to do some debugging on your end to figure out the particular part of your code that is at issue. Check your browser's network tools to see if the HTTP call to the backend is made correctly. Use the SQL Profiler to see if the SQL statement is made correctly, has the correct parameters, and has the right result.

Comment: from sql profiler insert not done meaning not send meaning statement jQuery not executed

Comment: after invistigate request api for jquery not made

Comment: Why use jQuery for calling the API instead doing it in the razor page using C#? It makes your code harder to maintain and debug. One of the big advantages of Blazor is not having to use JavaScript.

Comment: Blazor is a C# platform.  You should not be using JQuery except for media-- streaming video etc.   If you are asking this question, you should stop and go watch some Blazor tutorial series on YouTube.

Comment: ok can you only give me solution using jQuery and i will not use it on current situation I will use it on stream . i ask this question  because if i use jQuery I will know how to use it on blazor app

Comment: It has nothing to do with Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

> I create JS file insertdata.js on wwwroot folder js folder and add
> following code

and you refered:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/insertdata.js"></script>
```

by default,it should be

```
<script src="~/js/insertdata.js"></script>
```

And the codes here in your razor component:

```
async Task  Selectemp(string id)
    {
        selectedEmployeeId = id;
        selectedEmployeeId = emp!.First(c => c.employeeID.Equals(selectedEmployeeId)).employeeID;
        appsdata.OwnerFileNo = selectedEmployeeId;
        InsertData(emddata);
          
}



public async Task InsertData(EmployeeDetails owner)
    {
        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("insertData", owner);
    }
```

don't forget `await` before `InsertData(emddata);`

In mycase,I tried as below in a default Blazor Server App,and it works:

My static files:

[image]

in layout.cshtml:

```
<body>
.........
<script src="~/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/myjs.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(.....)));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OwnerController : ControllerBase
 {
       .......
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddOwnerFile")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] EmployeeDetails employeedetails)
        {
            var sql = "INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails (departementCode) VALUES ({0})";
            var affectrows=_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql,employeedetails.departementCode);
            return Ok();
        }
  
}
```

in counter Razor Component:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@using BlazorServerApp.Data

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(_=>IncrementCount())">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private EmployeeDetails empdetails = new EmployeeDetails() { EmployeeDetailsId = 1, departementCode = "Code" };

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        await InsertDataAsync(empdetails);
        
        currentCount++;
    }

    public async Task InsertDataAsync(EmployeeDetails owner)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("insertData", owner);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]